# MAC Sierra 10.12 use xcode to debug view hierarchy get empty, not show the view

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, ios7, ios8

I recently encountered a problem, I use VMware to install the mac system, the use of xcode debug view hierarchy function, encountered a blank interface, but the left shows the view inside the UIViews elements, the middle is a blank nothing, Do not know why, hope to get everyone's answer. 
Thank you

I am using a desktop, no wireless module。When I use Reveal to debug, also met the same problem. still empty and don't show any views.

The below picture is the problem I met :

[image]

I use Reveal and also met the same problem: 
[image]

Comment: Capture a screenshot with specific problem while debugging the `view hierarchy` and post it here.

Comment: I don't konw what you mean. My problem is why the center space is white. Maybe is my setting problem. I don't konw.  I use Reveal is the same problem. I am looing forward to your reply. @nayem

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer.
It's just what I found is pretty long and doesn't fit in a comment.

I am running Catalina 10.15.4 within qemu.
Thus, I guess this problem is related to virtual machine.

"Show Clipped Content" didn't work for me.
But after I clicked "Debug Memory Graph", xcode crashed and gave me:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread                                    
0   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff647be0c1 __dynamic_cast + 23                         
1   com.apple.Jet                   0x00007fff52785675 jet_context_OpenGL::create_program(jet_function*, jet_function*) + 69
2   com.apple.SpriteKit             0x00007fff3a3f4127 SKCRenderer::loadShaders() + 441       
3   com.apple.SpriteKit             0x00007fff3a3f6bcb SKCRenderer::SKCRenderer(std::__1::shared_ptr<jet_context>) + 767
4   com.apple.SpriteKit             0x00007fff3a32513e -[SKView _ensureRenderer] + 69        
5   com.apple.SpriteKit             0x00007fff3a325791 -[SKView _commonInit] + 648                                                                   
6   com.apple.SpriteKit             0x00007fff3a32b475 -[SKView initWithFrame:] + 109        
7   com.apple.DTGraphKitSpriteKitAssets 0x000000013b82267c 0x13b811000 + 71292                  
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff2a76ecc7 -[NSView init] + 44                                         
9   com.apple.dt.instruments.DTGraphKit 0x0000000111167d5e _sharedInit + 78                                         
10  com.apple.dt.instruments.DTGraphKit 0x0000000111167f38 -[DTObjectGridGraph initWithCoder:] + 56
11  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration    0x00000001200fceda IBCreateSwappedObjectForCoder + 78
12  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration    0x00000001200fccf1 -[NSClassSwapper(IBNSClassSwapperPrivate) ibSwizzledInitWithCoder:] + 63
13  com.apple.UIFoundation          0x00007fff5e4a7650 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 747
14  com.apple.UIFoundation          0x00007fff5e4a784b UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1254
15  com.apple.UIFoundation          0x00007fff5e4a7358 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 251
16  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff2a70722c -[NSView initWithCoder:] + 1846
17  com.apple.dt.DVTStructuredLayoutKit 0x00000001060dae07 -[DVTLayoutView_ML initWithCoder:] + 42
18  com.apple.dt.DVTUserInterfaceKit    0x00000001061f356e -[DVTBorderedView initWithCoder:] + 97
19  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration    0x00000001200fceda IBCreateSwappedObjectForCoder + 78
20  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration    0x00000001200fccf1 -[NSClassSwapper(IBNSClassSwapperPrivate) ibSwizzledInitWithCoder:] + 63
21  com.apple.UIFoundation          0x00007fff5e4a7650 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 747
22  com.apple.UIFoundation          0x00007fff5e4a7358 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 251
23  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff2a6cb981 -[NSNibConnector initWithCoder:] + 89
24  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff2a6cb8c4 -[NSNibOutletConnector initWithCoder:] + 414
…
```

Thus, I guess it is related to OpenGL.

I tried to see if it would work with a real device (above happened on an iOS simulator).
But I failed to connect my iPhone to the guest macOS.
It stuck with the hosting Ubuntu.

Gonna to dig deeper …

Answer (score 1):

Your `view` might be swapped out from visible screen (maybe you scrolled right/left or up/down more).

So try scrolling vertically and/or horizontally to make your `view` inside your viewable area.

Besides you can try clicking the `orient to 3D` button that resets your view in the middle of your editor's screen. Here is a screenshot for better understanding:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for your wonderful answer, but I'm sure not to view the overflow of the screen, I can click on the blank when the click to the control, that is, the view is displayed in the middle, but did not render out, do not know why, online Some people say that because there is no reason for Aridrop, my virtual machine inside the mac system is no AirDrop. Although not resolved, still want to thank your answer.

Comment: Not this but I tapped the "Show clipped content" button that is in the same place as "Try clicking here" button and it worked.Thanks for the inspiration!